# DB2 Auto generated Column / GENERATED ALWAYS pros and cons over sequence

Tags: db2

Earlier we were using '**GENERATED ALWAYS**' for generating the values for a primary key. But now it is suggested that we should, instead of using 'GENERATED ALWAYS' , use sequence for populating the value of primary key. What do you think can be the reason of this change? It this just a matter of choice?

Earlier Code:

```
CREATE TABLE SCH.TAB1
 (TAB_P         INTEGER         NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, NO CACHE),
.
.
);
```

Now it is

```
CREATE TABLE SCH.TAB1
 (TAB_P         INTEGER ),
.
.
);
```

now while inserting, generate the value for TAB_P via sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use identity columns more than sequences, but I'll compare the two for you.

Sequences can generate numbers for any purpose, while an identity column is strictly attached to a column in a table.

Since a sequence is an independent object, it can generate numbers for multiple tables (or anything else), and is not affected when any table is dropped. When a table with a identity column is dropped, there is no memory of what value was last assigned by that identity column.

A table can have only one identity column, so if you want to want to record multiple sequential numbers into different columns in the same table, sequence objects can handle that.

The most common requirement for a sequential number generator in a database is to assign a technical key to a row, which is handled well by an identity column. For more complicated number generation needs, a sequence object offers more flexibility.

Comment: +1 for "Since a sequence is an independent object, it can generate numbers for multiple tables (or anything else), and is not affected when any table is dropped"

Comment: I also would like to point out that you have the option of using an identity column that is GENERATED BY DEFAULT. This will allow you to migrate in old data without having its identity value clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

This might probably be to handle ids in case there are lots of deletes on the table.

For eg: In case of identity, if your ids are
1
2
3

Now if you delete record 3, your table will have
1
2

And then if your insert a new record, the ids will be
1
2
4

As opposed to this, if you are not using an identity column and are generating the id using code, then after delete for the  new insert you can calculate id as max(id) + 1, so the ids will be in order
1
2
3

I can't think of any other reason, why an identity column should not be used.

Comment: max(id) + 1 ?
what will happen if ID values are 1,2,3,4
and now if 2 is deleted, then even by your case the next value of ID will be '5', 
also i said "generate the value for TAB_P via sequence", not by any calculation.

Comment: In that case, it will be 1,3,4,5 unless action is taken to re-adjust the id values for all rows after the deleted row which in itself will be a very time-consuming task for large no of records.

Answer (score 0):

Heres something I found on the publib site:

**Comparing IDENTITY columns and sequences**

While there are similarities between IDENTITY columns and sequences, there are also differences. The characteristics of each can be used when designing your database and applications.

An identity column has the following characteristics:

- An identity column can be defined as
  part of a table only when the table
  is created. Once a table is created,
  you cannot alter it to add an
  identity column. (However, existing
  identity column characteristics might
  be altered.)
- An identity column
  automatically generates values for a
  single table.
- When an identity
  column is defined as GENERATED
  ALWAYS, the values used are always
  generated by the database manager.
  Applications are not allowed to
  provide their own values during the
  modification of the contents of the
  table.

A sequence object has the following characteristics:

- A sequence object is a database
  object that is not tied to any one
  table.
- A sequence object generates
  sequential values that can be used in
  any SQL or XQuery statement.
- Since a sequence object can be used
  by any application, there are two
  expressions used to control the
  retrieval of the next value in the
  specified sequence and the value
  generated previous to the statement
  being executed. The PREVIOUS VALUE
  expression returns the most recently
  generated value for the specified
  sequence for a previous statement
  within the current session. The NEXT
  VALUE expression returns the next
  value for the specified sequence. The
  use of these expressions allows the
  same value to be used across several
  SQL and XQuery statements within
  several tables.

While these are not all of the characteristics of these two items, these characteristics will assist you in determining which to use depending on your database design and the applications using the database.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why anyone would EVER use an identity column rather than a sequence.
Sequences accomplish the same thing and are far more straight forward.  Identity columns are much more of a pain especially when you want to do unloads and loads of the data to other environments.  I not going to go into all the differences as that information can be found in the manuals but I can tell you that the DBA's have to almost always get involved anytime a user wants to migrate data from one environment to another when a table with an identity is involved because it can get confusing for the users.  We have no issues when a sequence is used.  We allow the users to update any schema objects so they can alter their sequences if they need to.

Comment: A better answer would be based on 'best practices' and not ease of use for loading and unloading data.  There is nothing cryptic about an identity column and it allows the database to manage what should be managed by the database.