# @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) not working as thought

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, derby

I'm trying to persist an object to a database.  Keep getting 'Column ID cannot accept null value error'.  My object looks like this:

```
    @Entity
public class TestTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id = 0;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=256)
    private String data = "";

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

My persist function:

```
public static synchronized boolean persistObject(Object obj){
        boolean success = true;
        EntityManager em = null;
        EntityTransaction tx = null;
        try{
            em = getEmf().createEntityManager();
            tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            em.persist(obj);
            tx.commit();

        } catch (Exception e){
            success = false;
        } finally{
            try{
                em.close();
            } catch(Exception e){
                //nothing
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may use GenerationType.TABLE. 
That way, jpa uses a sequence table for id assigment and you may never need to generate sequence or auto-increment values or triggers that lowers portability.

Also note that in java int type is initiated with 0 default, so you may get rid of that also.

Comment: @Null: Then accept the answer (by clicking on the checkmark beside it) so that cguler gets a small reward for offering it. Doing so also helps to encourage others to answer your other questions well.

Comment: @cguler This also worked for me, but I don't know why GenerationType.Table works and Auto doesn't. Can you explain me or refer me?

Comment: @ChristianVielma the point is, AUTO defaults to IDENTITY. You may need to try the GenerationType.IDENTITY explicitly and see if it works to see if it is a problem with AUTO setting. But probably your db configuration does not support it. However GenerationType.TABLE creates a table and uses it for generating the keys and this setting should work on all rdbms. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Really thanks @cguler I'll check more about that in the documentation and see why it doesn't work with my Postgres configuration.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was about bad dialect:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

instead of:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

when I switched to the production database. Hibernate tried to use strategy prepared for different db engine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with a similar manifestation to yours. I eventually discovered that the configuration of my database connection was wrong: I was connecting to an old database that had an incorrect schema. The new schema declared the primary-key column as

> `"ID" BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)`

so [the database itself automatically generated the primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026936/db2-auto-generated-column-generated-always-pros-and-cons-over-sequence) whereas the old schema declared it as

> `"ID" INTEGER NOT NULL`

Hibernate executed the correct code for the new schema, which failed on the old schema because the old schema demanded the SQL `INSERT` provide a value for the `ID` column.

Answer (score 1):

Or try with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`
instead of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`.

Comment: or try   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate fails in silent and mysterious ways when the ID column is an Int. Try changing it to Long in the code and an unsigned 64-bit integer in the database. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone arrives at this thread with the same problem as me. I have been struggling with this for some hours now, and just want to post my solution. It seemed the ID was always set to 0, and that threw an error.

The id property in the model must be of type "Long" or "Integer" and not "long" or "integer" (notice the capitalization). I had put "long", which is a primitive type and cannot be null. Therefore the default value was 0 and Hibernate didn't realize that it was a new entity and tried to save it with ID = 0, something that obviously did not work.

Changing this into the reference type "Long", which can be null, solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem and somehow for me long work instead of LONG type :). As a workarround I converted id column in database as SERIEL. I am using postgres db.