# Hibernate null constraint violation on @Id with @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, annotations, playframework

I am using Hibernate 4.1.3 (JPA) on the Play! framework. The database is PostgreSQL 8.4.2. The schema was generated using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto="update"`.

Short version: I have a class that has an `@Id` field that is a `@GeneratedValue`. Sometimes, when `persist`ing it, I get a null-column violation, why?

---

More details:

I have a really simple class that I want to save to the database, that looks like this:

```
@Entity
class MyObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @NotNull
    public String email;

    public Integer total;
}
```

I usually create an instance of MyObject, I assign a value to `email` and `total` fields while `id` is null and I save it via `EntityManager.persist()`. Hibernate gets an id for the new object and saves it to the DB.

However sometimes, I get the following stacktrace:

```
2012-05-19 00:45:16,335 - [ERROR] - from org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [SqlExceptionHelper.java:144] in play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-6 
ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

2012-05-19 00:45:16,350 - [ERROR] - from application in play-akka.actor.actions-dispatcher-6 


! @6ad7j3p8p - Internal server error, for request [POST /method] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint]]
```

How is this possible? How can I track down the problem?

Here's the relevant DDL generated by Hibernate:

```
CREATE TABLE myobject (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    email character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    physical integer
);

CREATE SEQUENCE hibernate_sequence
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO MINVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE ONLY dailydetailedscore
    ADD CONSTRAINT dailydetailedscore_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: Add the DDL generated by Hibernate for your database. GenerationType.AUTO means that you have elected to have Hibernate select a generation type for you, which is probably not what you intended to do.

Comment: The schema looks fine. This might be an interaction problem between Play! and JPA. Have you tried using an identity column instead?

Comment: @Perception "`GenerationType.AUTO` means that you have elected to have Hibernate select a generation type" But it should select a good one. Quoth the JPA standard [emphasis added]: "the persistence provider should pick an *appropriate* strategy for the particular database." A strategy that violates a NOT NULL constraint could never be "appropriate". Does this indicate a defect in Hibernate?

Comment: I get a similar problem with Spring+Hibernate+Derby.

Comment: See also this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129552/generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto-not-working-as-thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the annotation `@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name = “test-hilo-strategy”, strategy = “hilo”)`:

```
@Id
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name=“hilo-strategy”, strategy = “hilo”)
@GeneratedValue(generator = ”hilo-strategy”)
```

As someone noted above, `AUTO` does not do what you think.  It uses the underlying DB to determine how to generate values.  It may pick sequences (for oracle), identity column (for mssql), or something else that is db specific.

The approach here uses an internal strategy that Hibernate supplies called "hilo".

See chapter 5 of the Hibernate reference manual dealing with "Generator" for a full description of what each of the supplied ones does.

Comment: Actually, the AUTO strategy does what it is supposed to do on Postgres (namely, use a sequence to generate unique identifiers). It turns out that my code works fine on PostgreSQL 8.4.4, thus I suppose it is a version-specific bug. The hilo generator works just fine on 8.4.2, so I am just going to use that.

Comment: In Postgres 8.4.20 I'm getting the same bug as the OP using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` , but this solution is not fixing it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the OP solution nor Matt's solution worked with my PostgreSQL 9.3.

But this one works:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="identifier", sequenceName="mytable_id_seq", allocationSize=1)  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="identifier")
```

Replace `mytable_id_seq` with the name of the sequence that generates your id.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hibernate method:- save(String entityName, Object object) 
Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier.

**Do not use :-   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) for primary key if you want to persist user define Id**.

For detail:-
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

In mycase i was using **Identity** generation strategy and i have set the wrong data type in Postgres. Following steps i performed to debug the problem.

set

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in application.properties and Drop the tables.

By this hibernate will automatically create the schema for you on the basis of your data-type.I noticed change in the datatype of id field.

Now when i tried any post requests, everything worked fine.