# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException on add product

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, h2

So when I wanted to add a product to the database from the frontend form and the following error occurs :

```
Nov 30, 2017 8:28:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into Product (id, category_id, price, productDescription, productname, quantity) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
Nov 30, 2017 8:28:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/project1_frontend] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into Product (id, category_id, price, productDescription, productname, quantity) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]] with root cause
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into Product (id, category_id, price, productDescription, productname, quantity) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:345)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:797)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:615)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:608)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
    at com.niit.dao.ProductDaoImpl.saveOrUpdateProduct(ProductDaoImpl.java:45)
    at com.niit.services.ProductServiceImpl.saveOrUpdateProduct(ProductServiceImpl.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.saveOrUpdateProduct(Unknown Source)
    at com.niit.controllers.ProductController.saveorUpdateProduct(ProductController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Product class :

```
package com.niit.product;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;



@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) //Automatically generate value for Id using sequence
private int id; //product.setId(0)

@NotEmpty(message="Product name is mandatory")
private String productname;//product.setProductName("pen")
@NotEmpty(message="Product description cannot be blank")
private String productDescription;

private int quantity;
@Min(value=10,message="Minimum price is 10")
private double price;
@ManyToOne
private Category category;//product.setCategory().setId(1)
@Transient
private MultipartFile image; //image will not get persisted in the table
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getProductname() {
    return productname;
}
public void setProductname(String productname) {
    this.productname = productname;
}
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}
public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}
public MultipartFile getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void setImage(MultipartFile image) {
    this.image = image;
}


}
```

The Category class for which the id is PK and acts as category_id or FK for the Product class:

```
package com.niit.product;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String categoryname;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
private List<Product> products;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCategoryname() {
    return categoryname;
}
public void setCategoryname(String categoryname) {
    this.categoryname = categoryname;
}

}
```

Here is my ProductController :

```
package com.niit.controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.niit.product.Category;
import com.niit.product.Product;
import com.niit.services.ProductService;
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
private ProductService productService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/all/getallproducts")
public ModelAndView getAllProducts(){
    List<Product> products=productService.getAllProducts();
    //productlist - logical view name [productlist.jsp]
    //products - model attribute [use this attribute in jsp]
    //products - List<Product> data 
    return new ModelAndView("productlist","productsAttr",products);
    //JSTL and EL 
}
    // all/viewproduct/1  [id=1]
    @RequestMapping(value="/all/viewproduct/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getProduct(@PathVariable int id){
        Product product=productService.getProduct(id);
        return new ModelAndView("viewproduct","product",product);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/deleteproduct/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(HttpServletRequest request,@PathVariable int id){
        String rootDirectory=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        Path path=Paths.get(rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF/resources/images/"+id+".png");
        if(Files.exists(path)){
            try {
                Files.delete(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return "redirect:/all/getallproducts";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/getproductform")
    public String getProductForm(@RequestParam(required=false)int id,Model model){
        if(id==0)//add product
        model.addAttribute("product",new Product());//1
        else{ //edit product
            Product product=productService.getProduct(id);//select * from product where id=?
            model.addAttribute("product",product);
        }
        //SELECT * from Category
        List<Category> categoriesList=productService.getAllCategories();
        model.addAttribute("categories",categoriesList);
        return "productform";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/saveorupdateproduct")
    public String saveorUpdateProduct(HttpServletRequest request,@Valid @ModelAttribute(name="product")  Product product,BindingResult result,Model model) {//3
        if(result.hasErrors()){//constraint violation
            List<Category> categories=productService.getAllCategories();
            model.addAttribute("categories",categories);
            return "productform";
        }
        System.out.println(product.getProductname());

        productService.saveOrUpdateProduct(product); //insert and update
        String rootDirectory=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println(rootDirectory);
        Path path=Paths.get(rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF/resources/images/"+product.getId()+".png");
        MultipartFile prodImage=product.getImage();//uploaded image [jpeg,gif,..]
        try {
            prodImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//transfer the image to the file named productid.png
        return "redirect:/all/getallproducts";
    }

}
```

Shouldn't the AUTO generated strategy automatically generate id for product class as we add more products via the frontend dynamically?(Instead of encountering a null value for another entry of product) I'm new to hibernate and any help would be appreciated!

[Here is my product table at backend H2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzgC7.png)

Comment: Can you check the dialect which you are using in database configuration, also you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129552/generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto-not-working-as-thought

Comment: hibernateProperties.setProperty(
    "hibernate.dialect", **"org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"**);
  hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

This is the dialect in DB config. As per the link you shared, this dialect should be working fine.

Comment: And using generation type as TABLE throws DataIntegrityViolationException : Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY_KEY_1 ON PUBLIC.PRODUCT(ID) VALUES (1, 16)";

Comment: Its throwing violation because you already have entries in Product table with these ID values, I think you are doing development so delete entries from database and start from scratch with generation type as Table.

Comment: Thank you so much. Deleting all the data from table Product at backend and setting the generation type as TABLE worked. Products are now being added sequentially. It means TABLE auto generates IDs at backend but AUTO generation should've done the same for a new table too but failed. Why is there a difference here?

Comment: Also the product ID hence generated at the backend is now [32768, 32769...] Not [1,2..] Random index values set by the hibernate most probably.

Comment: Yeah, that hibernate thing, but if your main issue is resolved then let me paste it as an answer and you can accept it also.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Auto Generation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129552/generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto-not-working-as-thought) and following this link if its throwing violation exception then its because you already have entries in Product table with these ID values.

I think you are doing development so delete entries from database and start from scratch with generation type as Table. May be Generation type Auto does not work with H2.