# Add @GeneratedValue on a later point, when data in table is already present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

An entity which has ID but the data in corresponding table was added manually, for this reason @GeneratedValue annotation was never added. Now I need to create records in this table through code and want my ID to be auto-incremented.
On adding `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) Integer id;`
The exception I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129552/generatedvaluestrategy-generationtype-auto-not-working-as-thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the column definition in the database to add a default value of "AUTO_INCREMENT".

For Mysql:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable MODIFY COLUMN ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I think you should also set the next AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table to the actual maximum value of the id + 1:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = new_value;
```

Comment: The ID is also a foreign key to another table so I get the exception
Error Code: 1833. Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK' of table 'other_table'

Comment: Ihaven't tried this, but you can try to disable foreign key checks before the alter-statement with ```SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;``` and enable them again after the alter with ```SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;```  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks