# DB2 naming a sequence on create table

Tags: sql, db2, ddl

This may seem like a pointless question, but I'll ask it.

In creating a DDL, I want to have all my relationships and "extra" information NAMED, so when the db throws an error its using MY name and not some auto-generated ID

this is great for my relations and indexes, however I've noticed that DB2 stores "sequences", and it just names them... I can't seem to figure out how to name them in the create script - and going in AFTER creation to figure out what is what is not an option.

EXAMPLE

```
SEQUENCE MY_SCHEMA.SQL131021121240860 is what DB2 named it when I created
```

What I'd like to do

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 0 0 CACHE 20;
```

I've tried this BEFORE the CREATE TABLE, and AFTER... but the sequences ALWAYS go in with this 'SQL131021121240..' naming

Here are the two ways I've tried it....

```
-- BEFORE, as my ERD software does...
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SCHEMA.TEST_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 32767 0 0 CACHE 20;

CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.TEST (
  ID SMALLINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1 ) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT MY_SCHEMA_TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
) IN STORE16K;


-- AFTER, as it makes sense to me, that the table has to exist first
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.TEST2 (
  ID SMALLINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1 ) NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT MY_SCHEMA_TEST2_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ID )
) IN STORE16K;
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SCHEMA.TEST2_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1000 MAXVALUE 32767 0 0 CACHE 20;
```

In both cases a sequence that is named by the DB shows up in the SEQUENCES folder....

can it be done? is there a reason NOT to do it?, I just hate seeing labels like "SQL131021121240860" showing up in diagrams and DDLs....

In doing some more reading, it appears as though I don't understand SEQUENCES, however I think my question is still relevant. I'd still like to NAME them.

I'm confused by the fact that sequences get automatically created on identity fields - the comments in this post ( [DB2 Auto generated Column / GENERATED ALWAYS pros and cons over sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026936/db2-auto-generated-column-generated-always-pros-and-cons-over-sequence) ) make it seem as thou it's an either/or proposition to use 'generated identity' or 'sequences' - but the behavior of CREATE TABLE with a single column  as identity DOES create a sequence...NOT ONLY that but it appears as though it's a 1:1 - which may be needed for identity, and its most likely that a defined sequence can be used by other things.. I get that they are "not bound" to tables specifically....

either way - my question of HOW to NAME them, instead of letting the DB name this is still my point.

Thx

Comment: For completeness, which version/platform of DB2?  I'm pretty sure that the auto-named sequences are from the identity columns, _not_ the named sequences you are creating.  Dunno how to name them though (I'd have assumed they'd be named `schema/table/column` or something).  The reason why it'd be an either/or is that identity columns/primary keys are required to have **UNIQUE** values - if you mix sequences in you may get duplicate values.  The fact that identity column value generators are built from a sequence is an implementation detail, so you may not be able to do too much about it...

Answer (score 0):

As you have already realized, DB2 implicitly creates a sequence for each `IDENTITY` column, and there is no way to supply the name for such a sequence. Your requirement to have custom names seems arbitrary.